# Jquery: unable to figure out why prependTo method of Jquery is not working in this example

Tags: jquery

I am unable to figure out why the `prependTo` method in the below example is not functioning. I am unable to determine why I am unable to see `"I am new outer div"` text. The following is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    var $newDiv = $("<div></div>")
     .text("I am new outer div")
     .attr("style","color:red");

      var $innerDiv = $("<div></div>");
      $innerDiv.attr("style","color:green")
      .text("I am new inner Div");

     var $finalDiv = $innerDiv.prependTo($newDiv)

      $("div").append($finalDiv)
    })
  </script>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span></span>
<div id="div1" title="My DIV1">DIV1</div>
<div id="div2" title="MY DIV2">DIV2</div>
<h1></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The following is the output:

```
DIV1
I am new inner Div
DIV2
I am new inner Div
```

I will appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: check this.. https://jsfiddle.net/naveencgr/41kvncno/

Comment: I'm not sure what are actually trying to do but if you want to prepend the contents of newDiv to innerDiv, then use .append instead of appendTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div").append($newDiv);
```

The `.prependTo()` method returns a reference to what you were prepending, so your `$finalDiv` and `$innerDiv` both refer to the inner div. So `$("div").append($finalDiv.parent())` would also work, but you don't need the `$finalDiv` variable at all: the `$newDiv` variable continues to refer to the outer div even after you prepend things to it, and the `$innerDiv` variable continues to refer to the inner one even after it is prepended.

In context:

```js
$(function(){
  var $newDiv = $("<div></div>")
    .text("I am new outer div")
    .attr("style","color:red");

  var $innerDiv = $("<div></div>");
  $innerDiv.attr("style","color:green")
    .text("I am new inner Div");

  $innerDiv.prependTo($newDiv)

  $("div").append($newDiv)
})
```

```css
div { border: thin black solid; padding: 5px; margin: 2px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" title="My DIV1">DIV1</div>
<div id="div2" title="MY DIV2">DIV2</div>
```